# How to crop image using spatie packages in laravel

Tags: laravel, crop, jquery-guillotine

I'm getting an error after following the documentation in [Spatie Media Library](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v7/converting-images/defining-conversions). The documentation says `Internally, spatie/image is used to manipulate the images. You can use any manipulation function from that package.`. So I tried to use the method `focalCrop()` but it returns an error.

This is what I'm currently working on:

**Controller**

```
auth()->user()
   ->addMediaFromRequest('file')
   ->toMediaCollection('coverphoto')
   ->addMediaConversion('thumb')
   ->focalCrop($cover_width, $cover_height, $coverX, $coverY);
```

**Error**

> Call to undefined method Spatie\MediaLibrary\Models\Media::addMediaConversion()

Answer (score 0):

the problem should be coming from your model User.

To use Spatie Media library, your model have to use the Trait InteractsWithMedia from spatie and eventually implement the interface HasMedia.

Check the official documentation of Spatie thers is some details about preparing your model for spatie.

Good luck

Comment: Where did you get the Trait `InteractsWithMedia`? Please include some references so I can check it as well

Comment: https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v8/basic-usage/preparing-your-model

Comment: I get an error: `Trait 'Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia' not found`. I'm using version 7 by the way https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v7/basic-usage/preparing-your-model

Comment: Okay so it was actually renamed. https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/issues/1825 . And my setup is fine, but I get the error `Call to undefined method Spatie\MediaLibrary\Models\Media::addMediaConversion()`